# Dependency property precedence. I want local value to be overridable

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, operator-precedence

I am writing a custom control. It has a dependency property that is supplied a "default" value by the control. This value can change at any time.

I want to be able to override this value via a style or whatever, but the dependency property precedence imposed by WPF means that my local default value always wins.

Is there any way of deferring to other sources when writing a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found a way around it.

I now expose two properties. A "Default" one that the control updates, and a standard one. In my default control style I bind the standard one to the default one so it gets the values, but can still be bound to something else in the xaml.

Comment: For your "Default" value, did you consider using `DependencyProperty`'s own `UnsetValue` property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue.aspx

Comment: Will you please post a simple implementation of your solution, at least in pseudocode? I don't get how to configure the bindings.

Answer (score 3):

You could trying clearing the local value via [`DependencyObject.ClearValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597464.aspx). I don't think you can change the [order of precedence for dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks, but unfortunately the control will be updating the local value quite regularly so any clears will get set again.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: I figured that would be the case. See my comment on your answer regarding using an "UnsetValue" for your dependency property.

Comment: Not sure whether you mean unset or clear. Clear will get overridden by my local value, and unset appears to be a static, so no good for my per instance control values?